# Angular: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of.. and property "id" is missing in type

Tags: angular, components

thanks for checking out this question. I'm pretty new to Angular and I have a problem I can't figure out. I'm working on a small thing, for practice, add text with a checkbox.. however, I haven't got that far yet. It fails with the errors:

```
Eerror TS2345: Argument of type '{ title: string; done: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: number; title: string; done: boolean; }'.

Property 'id' is missing in type '{ title: string; done: false; }'.
```

The code is task-list.component.ts

Here is my ts file. If you need more info just let me know. I'm clueless right now! Thank you

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mac-task-list',
  templateUrl: './task-list.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TaskListComponent {
  tasks = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Task 1', done: false},
    {id: 2, title: 'Task 2', done: true}
  ];

  addTask(title: string) { // fails here
    this.tasks.push({
      title, done: false
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you push, you also need an id.. that is the complaint..

Comment: Thanks, I can't figure out how to get the id into the push.. is there a snippet of code anywhere I could look at? Nothing I do works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the missing props:

For testing purpose, create a counter to generate an id value:

```
countId = 0;
//...

addTask(title: string) { // fails here
    this.tasks.push({
      id: this.countId++,
      title, done: false
    });
  }
```

Otherwise declare id prop as optional property.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have no idea how to do that. I've been searching and getting nowhere. Sorry.

Comment: For testing purpose add a counter to generate the id value. See the updates